# Error in setting SIGNING_KEY in djangorestframework-simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

It's a bit odd! I have separated the base settings from the local settings. For instance, I moved SECRET_KEY into an other file called local.py as my local settings:

```
SECRET_KEY = env(
    "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY",
    default="MY_DEFAULT_SEC_KEY"
)
```

and the following is my simple-jwt settings in base.py which does not contain any variable called SECRET_KEY(since I moved it into local.py):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer", ),
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=30),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "SIGNING_KEY": env("SIGNING_KEY"),
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
}
```

I want to set a different SIGNING_KEY but I get the following error:

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/settings.py",
> line 19, in  celery_worker-1  |     "SIGNING_KEY":
> settings.SECRET_KEY, celery_worker-1  |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ celery_worker-1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
> line 111, in **getattr** celery_worker-1  |     raise
> ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
> celery_worker-1  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The
> SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

I don't need to set SECRET_KEY according to the documentation when I set a different SIGNING_KEY. However, it says I need to give it a value. What is the problem?